# Set up Storybook to work with Next.js's Link tag

Tags: next.js, storybook

I'm trying to set up Storybook for a Next.js project. I have a component that render the [`Link`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) tag from Next.js. My problem is that when I load this component, Storybook throws the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'pageLoader' of null
   at Link.handleRef
```

What does one have to do to get Storybook working with Next.js Routing, specifically rendering the `Link` tag?

**Update:** Code that causes the error:

```js
// button-component.js
import Link from 'next/link.js';
import t from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

function Button({ as, children, href, ...props }) {
  const isExternal = href && href.startsWith('http');
  const a = (
    <a href={href} {...props}>
      {children}
    </a>
  );

  if (href) {
    return isExternal ? (
      a
    ) : (
      <Link href={href} as={as}>
        {a}
      </Link>
    );
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" {...props}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
}

Button.propTypes = {
  as: t.string,
  children: t.node,
  href: t.string,
};

export default React.memo(Button);
```

```js
// button.stories.js
import React from 'react';

import Button from './button-component';

export default {
  title: 'Button',
};

export const standardButton = () => <Button>Standard Button</Button>;

export const internalLink = () => <Button href='/buy'>
  Internal Link
</Button>;

export const externalLink = () => (
  <Button target="_blank" href="https://www.hopin.to">
    External Link
  </Button>
);
```

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Which next version?

Comment: @Cully Sure, done!

Comment: @felixmosh Next.js: "9.1.7", Storybook: "5.3.1"

Comment: Pls add Error Stack-trace

Comment: @felixmosh The full error stack trace is useless, because it points to the compiled modules by Storebook.

Comment: Can you setup a small repo that reproduces this issue?

Comment: What's your file structure for this project? Is `button.stories.js` a next.js page?

Comment: @Cully No. Button.stories.js is simply for Storybook.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Did upgrading to the canary release of next.js not work?

Comment: And also, Next.js 9.2 came out yesterday. I imagine updating to that would have the same effect.

Answer (score 5):

I found an issue reported about this on Next.js's github: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/9951

It was reported only 5 days ago, so you could be having the same issue. The resolution is to upgrade to nextjs `v9.1.8-canary.6`. Reading more about this and looking at the source code, this is likely your problem. Also, there are more recent canary builds of nextjs, if you want to try something newer.

If that doesn't resolve it, my other guess is that you're getting errors because you're using `Link` outside of a Next.js page. Next.js may include dependencies for pages, behind the scenes. `Link` may rely on those dependencies and is throwing an error when they aren't found. If you want to test your components outside of Next.js pages, you could create a custom `Link` component that tests whether you're in Next.js and only renders `Link` if you are. For example:

```js
import Link from 'next/link'
import Router from 'next/router'

const CustomLink = ({children, ...otherProps}) => {
  const isPage = () => {
    // if we're in a next.js route, then Router.router will be set
    return Boolean(Router.router)
  }

  return isPage()
    ? (<Link {...otherProps}>{children}</Link>)
    : children
}
```

Then use `CustomLink` instead of `Link`.

Comment: Instead of `isPage()` function you can use `process.env.STORYBOOK === 'true'`. This approach won't hide errors in case your code will run outside storybook and for some reason without Router context

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found works similar as with `next/image`. To your `.storybook/preview.js` add following:

```js
import Link from "next/link";

Object.defineProperty(Link, "default", {
  configurable: true,
  value: (props) => <a {...props} />,
});
```